# How to consume a webApi from asp.net Web API to store result in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm wondering how to consume a WEBAPI from another ASP.Net Web API to store the response in a database.
I know how to consume a WEBAPI from clients like javascript,console application etc.

But the requirement is to pull the data from third party API by my WEBAPI & store the result in a database so that using my WEBAPI my clients request me for data.

Is it possible to do this with an Asp.Net Web API?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue here. The fact that your client itself is a Web API service makes no difference in how you can call a Web API service.

Comment: Please accept the answer instead of commenting with thanks, this way this question will no longer be open

Comment: I tried with RestSharp, its a simpler one. You can get full source code: https://github.com/garora/somestuff/tree/master/ConsumeWebAPI

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In this tutorial is explained how to consume a **web api** with C#, in this example a console application is used, but you can also use another **web api** to consume of course.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

You should have a look at the `HttpClient`

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/yourwebapi");
```

Make sure your requests ask for the response in JSON using the Accept header like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Now comes the part that differs from the tutorial, make sure you have the same objects as the other `WEB API`, if not, then you have to map the objects to your own objects. `ASP.NET` will convert the `JSON` you receive to the object you want it to be.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/yourcustomobjects").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var yourcustomobjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<YourCustomObject>>().Result;
    foreach (var x in yourcustomobjects)
    {
        //Call your store method and pass in your own object
        SaveCustomObjectToDB(x);
    }
}
else
{
    //Something has gone wrong, handle it here
}
```

please note that I use `.Result` for the case of the example. You should consider using the `async` `await` pattern here.

Comment: I have tried to consume service from A Console Application and am Successful. I am facing problem in consuming the same from Asp.Net WebApi. my queries are : 1. Where to write httpclient program in webApi project, since program should auto execute once in a day to update my DB? 2. Is it recommended to use nomysqldbs like mongo db or any other since my responce is JSON Objects?

Comment: Why are you using another web api if you want to execute it once a day? You could use your console application and windows scheduled tasks, to execute it once a day. Your database choice totally depends on other requirements.

Comment: I need to expose my DB to my clients through the WEB API which I am trying to implement. Its an intermediate service. Archietecture looks like..  WEB API(Third Party) <--> WEB API <--> client

Comment: Why not a console application with scheduled tasks for calling the other Web API, and your own Web API to expose your DB

Comment: wouldnt that create a CORs issue?

Answer (score 9):

For some unexplained reason this solution doesn't work for me (maybe some incompatibility of types), so I came up with a solution for myself:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/yourcustomobjects");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(data);
}
```

This way my content is parsed into a JSON string and then I convert it to my object.

Comment: for me, this soln works after adding data.result(instead of data) in below line of code

"var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(data);"

Comment: JsonConvert is located in newtonsoft.json package, get it from nuget package manger :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IEmployee _employeeRepositary;

    public EmployeeApiController()
    {
        _employeeRepositary = new EmployeeRepositary();
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create(EmployeeModel Employee)
    {
        var returnStatus = await _employeeRepositary.Create(Employee);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnStatus);
    }
}
```

Persistance

```
public async Task<ResponseStatusViewModel> Create(EmployeeModel Employee)
{    
    var responseStatusViewModel = new ResponseStatusViewModel();
    var connection = new SqlConnection(EmployeeConfig.EmployeeConnectionString);
                var command = new SqlCommand("usp_CreateEmployee", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                var pEmployeeName = new SqlParameter("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                pEmployeeName.Value = Employee.EmployeeName;
                command.Parameters.Add(pEmployeeName);


                try
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    command.Dispose();
                    connection.Dispose();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw ex;
                }
                return responseStatusViewModel;
            }
```

Repository

```
Task<ResponseStatusViewModel> Create(EmployeeModel Employee);

public class EmployeeConfig
{
    public static string EmployeeConnectionString;
    private const string EmployeeConnectionStringKey = "EmployeeConnectionString";
    public static void InitializeConfig()
    {
        EmployeeConnectionString = GetConnectionStringValue(EmployeeConnectionStringKey);
    }

    private static string GetConnectionStringValue(string connectionStringName)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName]);
    }
}
```