# Can a web api sit on remote server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

or must it be on the same server as the app calling it?  I am new to web api so i am going through some tutorials, but they all assume the web api is part of the mvc app.  Also, they show the calls to the api being done with javascript, but I want to make the calls in my MVC app controller. Is this possible?

Comment: WebAPI is same as webservice (not exactly) , you can call it from any C# layer. you can use HttpClient class to call your web api hosted on some other server.

See this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448690/how-to-consume-a-webapi-from-asp-net-web-api-to-store-result-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Api can live wherever you want it to. Is typical to see a limited API used mostly to handle AJAX for the MVC application live with the MVC application, mostly because it makes it simpler to construct URLs to the endpoints. If you host the Web Api externally, then you'll have to hardcode the API endpoint URLs, as there's no way to use something like `Url.Action` to generate them automatically, any more. Regardless, it's a perfectly acceptable way to handle things.

You will probably at least want to add the base URL for the Web Api as an app setting in your Web.config, though. That way, you don't end up with hardcoded references to a particular domain strewn all about your app. That makes moving your Web Api to a different domain much easier, especially when talking about going from development to production.

It is also entirely possible to use a Web Api within your actual controller actions. You'll just need to use something like `HttpClient` to connect to it and issue requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can host a Web API anywhere.

The only special thing to have into account when the Web API isn't in the same server that a web site that uses it, is that, by default, the Web API doesn't accept requests from a different domain. For example, if the web site is in "server1.com" and the Web API in "server2.com", then the calls to the Web API from the web server will be rejected.

If this is the case, you need to configure the Web API server to enable CORS (cross origin resource sharing), so that it accepts requests from a different domain. If you want more info about this, please look at this document:

- [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)